# Unexpected failure on JUnit test when using assertEquals

Tags: java, junit, warnings, testcase

I want to make a simple test to check the name attribute of my class `Player` using JUnit's `assertEquals` method. When I run the JUnit test, I get a failure with a warning(AssertionFailedError: No tests found in PlayerTest), what am I doing wrong?

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Player(int id){
        this.setId(id);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}

public class PlayerTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void NameTest(){
        Player player = new Player(1);
        player.setName("Roberto");
        String name = "Roberto";
        assertEquals(name, player.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: TestCase is causing problem. Remove it and try adding Assert.assertEquals(name, player.getName()); it should work. I tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is because you wrote a Junit 3 style test case (using `extends TestCase`) instead of the annotation driven Junit 4 style.

Here is a junit 4 style test would look like:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;


import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;


public class PlayerTest  {

    @Test
    public void NameTest(){
        Player player = new Player(1);
        player.setName("Roberto");
        String name= "Roberto";
        assertEquals(name,player.getName());
    }

}
```

Edit: See Sunil's answer to make it work in Junit-3 style.

Answer (score 0):

The function name should start with "test" for TestCase to understand that it is a test function to run. Remove the @Test annotation.

In this case, change `NameTest()` to `testName()`. It will work.